# Rotate object 360 degree with some tilted angle or in ellipse shape using css or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to rotate arm object on top of cylinder which is placed with some angle to get maxium view of full object.

Hence I need to rotate arm on top of cylinder which should look like it is tilted same as cylinder using css or javascript.

Help me to achive this. Thank you...

```
.scara-arm {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.scara-arm.autoplay {
  animation: rotatearm 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotatearm 8s linear infinite;
}
```

**[Demo with code](http://jsfiddle.net/zkjuw4v5/18/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give the arm a 3d look you need to rotate it in the X axis - this is in addition to the Z axis rotation that you're already doing.

```
.scara-arm {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateX(55deg);
}
```

Be aware, this needs to be changed in several places - all of your existing `transform: rotate` will need to be changed to `transform: rotateZ` before you add the `rotateX`.

Also you can improve the 3d effect by adding some perspective to the arm's container:

```
.circle-small {
  perspective: 75em;
}
```

I recommend you try playing around with the numbers for `perspective` (CSS line #43) and `rotateX` (CSS lines 77 and 252-268) to improve the 3d effect.

[Updated demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/k0z2n95w/)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [rotate3d()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d) transformation. You can define the axis and make it rotate around that.

You can give it as something like this:

```
@keyframes rotatearm {
      0%  { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0.6, 1.3, 0deg) }
    100%  { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0.6, 1.3, 360deg) }
}
```

These values might not look perfect (I just put some values which looked good), but I hope you get the idea. You can find the perfectly matching axis and set it.

Here is a sample fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/mpbz4f1v/4/)

Hope it helps :)